# php json response, handling error

Tags: php, json, api

I've receive a response $oResponse:

```
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'transaction' =>
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'sId' => string '55PT1U-ELU4Z8-7RDTJY' (length=20)
      public 'sDate' => string '2012-12-13 17:32:45' (length=19)
      public 'fAmount' => int -10
      public 'sCurrency' => string 'USD' (length=3)
      public 'fFee' => int 0
      public 'sType' => string '(api) Sent to' (length=13)
      public 'iTypeId' => string '12' (length=2)
      public 'sEmail' => string 'receiver@test.com' (length=19)
      public 'sDetails' => string 'Api send test' (length=12)
      public 'sStatus' => string 'Completed' (length=9)
  public 'status' => string 'ok' (length=2)
```

Then try to parse a status:

```
echo $oResponse->{5}->status;
```

But it doesn't working :(

Comment: Can you should the full `var_dump()`?

Comment: Ok - usual questions: What **does** it do? Do you get an error message in your server logs or on screen? If so, what is it?

Comment: var_dump($oResponse) return `object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["transaction"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (10) { ["sId"]=> string(20) "55PT1U-ELU4Z8-7RDTJY" ["sDate"]=> string(19) "2012-12-13 17:32:45" ["fAmount"]=> int(-10) ["sCurrency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["fFee"]=> int(0) ["sType"]=> string(13) "(api) Sent to" ["iTypeId"]=> string(2) "12" ["sEmail"]=> string(21) "receiver@test.com" ["sDetails"]=> string(19) "Api send test" ["sStatus"]=> string(9) "Completed" } ["status"]=> string(2) "ok" }`

Comment: it's working! echo $oResponse->status;

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this

```
echo $oResponse->status;
```